# war файл, установка приложения на сервер

Tags: java, hosting, war

Доброго времени суток! Создал проект в "идее" и пытаюсь залить его на сервер сейчас, согласно этой инструкции: [инструкция](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PJHhWg-rS64&t=147s)

одним с пунктов есть создание и отправка war-файла на сам сервер. Подскажите, где искать варник, и что в нем хранится. Ранее приложение запускал на локальном хосте(томкет).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

варник после билда должен быть в target каталоге.. что в нем - открой и посмотри.. деплоить модно вручную из интерфейса томката или из идеи, если проект с поддержкой мавен (нужны соответствующие настройки - проекта, томката и мавена)

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня его там нету. Можете дать более развернутый ответ? 
Мне нужен варник что б загрузить его на сервер. в структуре проекта есть war(exploded) , я сделал  build artifact, варника нету нигде)

Comment: обычно все посредством мавена делаю, а без него.. заходим в свойства проекта - артефакты.. в правом верхнем поле Type выбираем web application archive.. ниже добавляем что нужно, закрываем сохраняя свойства проекта, затем через меню Build -- Build arifacts..